# Error: Event service timed out - Unable to start listening

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

We are trying to use chaincode events in our node client. we have started the chaincode listener when we start the node server but after sometime we are getting a time out error and we are not able receive any chaincode events.

```
2020-09-02T10:46:44.772Z - error: [EventService]: EventService[peer1.org1.example.com] timed out after:3000
2020-09-02T10:46:44.774Z - error: [EventService]: send[peer1.org1.example.com] - #3 - Starting stream to peer1.org1.example.com failed
2020-09-02T10:46:44.774Z - error: [EventService]: send[peer1.org1.example.com] - #3 - no targets started - Error: Event service timed out - Unable to start listening
2020-09-02T10:46:44.775Z - error: [BlockEventSource]: Failed to start event service message=Event service timed out - Unable to start listening, stack=Error: Event service timed out - Unable to start listening
    at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/EventService.js:413:12)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
2020-09-02T10:47:41.717Z - error: [EventService]: on.error [peer1.org1.example.com] - #3- reject the promise - Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connection dropped
2020-09-02T10:47:41.718Z - error: [EventService]: on.end [peer1.org1.example.com] - #3- reject the promise
```